# why my if else doesnt work

Tags: bash

```bsh
confirm() {
local YES="Y"
local NO="N"
local CONT="C"
    while : 
    do
    echo –n "(Y)es/(N)o/(C)ontinue? {Y] "
        read answer
        answer=`echo "$answer" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
        echo "$answer"
        if [ "$answer"=$YES ]
        then
                echo "YES"
                return 0
        elif ["$answer"="$CONT" ]
        then
                echo "skip skip skip"
                return 2
        elif [ "$answer"="$NO" ]
        then
                echo "NO"
                return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

The ouput always echo `YES` and return 0, no matter what the input is.

Comment: how should i fix it

Answer (score 5):

You are missing mandatory whitespaces around the operator, i.e. `=` in your case:

```
if [ "$answer" = "$YES" ]
```

This concerns every condition.

Comment: bring out the popcorn